# How to echo text when $_GET variable called and url parsed in htacess?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to figure out how to echo a line of text when a link is clicked using the `$_GET` function.  Here is what I have right now:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="?action=albums">Albums</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="?music">Music</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='albums'){
echo'<h1>Albums</h1>';
}
?>
```

Here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lr/profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: It does not display the echoed string

Comment: Actually it does when i try it in another php file

Comment: Try changing your links to `<a href="thispage.php?action=albums">`

Comment: Jamie I tried that and it is the same result as my above code

Comment: is your file extension .html or .php? please change it to .php

Comment: it is neither my current file has its url changed using the htaccess file so the link to get to the page this code is on is <a href="<?php echo $user_data['username'];?>">Home</a>

Comment: try to var_dump($_GET) to check the variable contents.

Comment: Please try my `.htaccess` addition I posted in my answer. Replace the last line with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lr/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that code isn't part of `index.php`, or likewise isn't accessible at `http://yourhost/`, it won't work, because the `<a href="?action=albums">` doesn't go to whatever file you're in, it goes to the root. Try `<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>?action=albums">Albums</a>`.

If you have a `.htaccess` file, make sure your `RewriteRule` has `[QSA]` at the end of it, as well. Additionally, the `SCRIPT_NAME` code won't work if you use `RewriteRule`s, because `SCRIPT_NAME` gets you the real file name for the PHP script.

Comment: Ok it does the same thing but now if I click on it more than once it just keeps adding ?action=albums at the end of the url

Comment: Sorry about that. Try my edit (use `SCRIPT_NAME` instead of `REQUEST_URI`).

Comment: No that redirects me to the index page as it is part of my code I use a htaccess file to tidy up the url.

Comment: When I do click on my original codes albums link it does not redirect me anywhere it just adds the ?action=albums to the end of the url?

Comment: That's probably because of the `RewriteRule`. Add `[QSA]` to the end of your `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess`.

Comment: OK where exactly in my rule do i add that I edited my post to show my htaccess

Comment: Replace the last line with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lr/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]`.

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSs excellent you have no idea dririan how long it took me to figure this out, thanx alot man wish i could accept answer twice for you